# logs of child logger get displayed twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I cannot achieve proper logging of my module using python's standard `logging`. Yet it's a very simple case.
I have the following module hierarchy:

```
module\
  foo.py
  bar.py
```

I need to log from each of these modules with the following constraints:

1. all logs >= `INFO` from `module.foo` to the console (because what this module does is important and user must be notified live)
2. all logs from `module.*` into a file
3. all logs >= `WARNING` from `module.*` to the console

Here is the main code

```
import logging
import logging.config
import os
import yaml

def setup_logging():
    loadfrom = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.yml')
    # Load
    with open(loadfrom, 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

setup_logging()

foo = logging.getLogger('module.foo')
bar = logging.getLogger('module.bar')

foo.info('module.foo doing something')
foo.debug('module.foo debug data')

bar.info('module.bar doing something')
bar.error('module.bar something bad happened')
```

Here is the config I'm using

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    file:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        filename: 'log.log'
        formatter: simple
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
  module:
    level: WARNING
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: yes
  module.foo:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: yes # If yes, gets displayed twice. If false, entry is missing in log file
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file]
```

And here is the output :

```
2017-09-21 10:48:39,679 - module.foo - INFO - module.foo doing something
2017-09-21 10:48:39,679 - module.foo - INFO - module.foo doing something
2017-09-21 10:48:39,681 - module.bar - ERROR - module.bar something bad happened
```

The `log.info` from the child module gets displayed twice, because `propagate` field is set to yes in the config.
Setting it to false solves the issue in the console but breaks the log file because the entry is missing in it.

How can I solve this ? Any alternatives to the standard library that I personnally find counterintuitive ?

## EDIT 1

New config after @wmorell's answer:

```
handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    file:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        filename: 'log.log'
        formatter: simple
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
  module:
    level: WARNING
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: yes
  module.foo:
    level: DEBUG    <- set this to debug
    handlers: [file, console] <- Add file here
    propagate: false
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file]
```

Console output is OK:

```
2017-09-21 11:14:51,174 - module.foo - INFO - module.foo doing something
2017-09-21 11:14:51,174 - module.bar - ERROR - module.bar something bad happened
```

Log output is not ok, misses the call to `log.info('module.bar')`:

```
2017-09-21 11:18:34,335 - module.foo - INFO - module.foo doing something
2017-09-21 11:18:34,335 - module.foo - DEBUG - module.foo debug data
2017-09-21 11:18:34,335 - module.bar - ERROR - module.bar something bad happened
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `file` handler explicitly to the logger definitions, and then duplicate the `console` handler to filter out different log levels:

```
handlers:
  console_info:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  console_warning:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    filename: 'log.log'
    formatter: simple
    encoding: utf8
loggers:
  module:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file, console_warning]
    propagate: false
  module.foo:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file, console_info]
    propagate: false
```

Logs get filtered at the logger definition first, so the `module` and `module.foo` loggers must allow `DEBUG` if those are to make it to the log file. The loggers then forward messages to all handlers, and handlers can drop messages below their configured thresholds; so you want a handler that will drop `INFO` logs for the base `module` logger, and a handler that will allow `INFO` logs for the more specific `module.foo` logger.

Comment: It's better but not there yet. I had to set `module.foo.level = DEBUG` otherwise the `log.debug('module.foo ..')` was not displayed. And even with that, the `log.info('module.bar')` is still missing from the log. Any ideas ?

Comment: Updated answer based on question change. Hope that helps.